# An error has occured in this script on this page google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tableau-api

I am showing customer segmentation information on Tableau that is connected to a database(Vertica). I have connected Tableau to Google maps, that if clicked on a point on the tableau map will show the street view on Google maps.

The connection works perfectly fine and it shows me the view. But whenever I click on the map, it shows me an error that says

```
'An error has occurred in this script on this page'.
```

I have tried to resolve this by disabling scripting errors on internet explorer on the internet options and changing the default browser to Google chrome. Sadly nothing works. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Uh, what is the relation to Java here? I think you meant javascript.

Comment: yes it is javascript! thank you!

Comment: What does your URL action look like? Have you verified that it is possible to paste that link directly into a browser and that it works?

Comment: Did you get this message with Internet Explorer?

Comment: yes i got this message on IE too, and when i copy pasted the URL on my web browser it works fine! well, tableau tries to show the map on the default browser only rite? my current default browser is Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Tableau uses Explorer regardless of your default browser. Here is a link that may help.

http://www.dataplusscience.com/ScriptingError.html